# Pig script DISTINCT not filtering out duplicate rows

Tags: hadoop, scripting, apache-pig

Running a pig script as follows on a table with millions of records:

```
A = LOAD '/this/that..' USING PigStorage(',') AS (F1:chararray, F2:chararray...);
CleanedCol1 = FOREACH A GENERATE LOWER(TRIM(REPLACE(F1,'[^a-zA-Z0-9-]',''))) AS F1, '' as F2...;
CleanedCol2 = FOREACH A GENERATE...

Combined = UNION CleanedCol1, CleanedCol2
CombinedSorted = ORDER Combined by F1;
CombinedDistinct = DISTINCT CombinedSorted

STORE CombinedDistinct INTO 'this/that' USING PigStorage(',')
```

The CleanedCols run the `LOWER(TRIM(REPLACE))` functions on a few of the various columns that are loaded, which I shortened for my sanity.

Despite the `DISTINCT` at the end, I'm left with duplicates rows which prolongs our scripts needlessly. I don't see anything relating to `DISTINCT` and limits based on number of records so I'm not sure why it isn't working. Can someone clue me in on why I'm seeing duplicates?

Comment: Can you provide an example of duplicates? `DISTINCT` should work, but maybe the rows are subtly different in a way you can't see, like a single space vs two spaces.

Comment: @savagedata We end up with comma delimited rows like the following: '12345abc,,,dvm85,,,'. I've pulled the raw results from HDFS and made direct comparisons in Notepad++ with 'Show all Characters" selected. Each duplicate is an exact match down to the line feeds at the end of the rows. Now this are large data sets and results do come back in multiple part files. Is it possible that part files are being compared on a part by part basis?

Comment: Comparing PigStorage (text) output can be misleading.  For example, empty string and null both show up as ",,".   Or type difference can also become an issue.

Comment: @Koji I think you're on to something. So we `LOAD` each column as a chararray but the `LOWER(TRIM...)` functions are run on specific columns. If I remove those functions/columns, we aren't seeing the duplicates, but I need to retain that functionality in some way. Is there a way to force the script to treat these empty/null field as the same so the `DISTINCT` works as intended?

Comment: Try running with pig -Daggregate.warning=false .  Maybe one of  lower/trim/replace is failing unexpectedly and returning null.

Comment: Or, add a followup step which converts all null to an empty string.

Comment: @Koji Close. I converted the empty strings to null since it was faster. Thanks for sticking with me though! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was how Pig dealt with columns that had nothing but space characters. When running the `trim` on an empty column, it would give the appearance of a `null` value but would be treated differently in the `distinct` comparison. I cleaned the values out by running the following on each column and my duplicate problem was solved:

```
TableClean = FOREACH A GENERATE (Col1 matches '^[\\s]*$' ? null : Col1) AS Col1...
```